# What does it mean for a state to have a negative partial decay width?

Tags: particle-physics, astrophysics, nuclear-physics

I don't understand what it means when a particular decay mode has a negative partial decay width. I'm guessing the total decay width for a particular system must always be positive (now **that** wouldn't make much sense to me), but I'm not quite sure  how the negative partial decay width plays in.

What does it mean when a particular decay mode has a negative partial width? Have I misunderstood anything?

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Can you add a reference to where that table comes from?

Comment: http://journals.aps.org/prc/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevC.78.025803

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative sign for the partial decay widths denote the sign of the corresponding reduced width amplitude in the R-Matrix formalism, which is what the author of this paper (and everybody else analyzing cross sections of low-energy nuclear reactions) is using to do his analyses. He's using the R-Matrix code SAMMY, which sadly has very little documentation.

The partial decay width of a state is parameterized by the square of the reduced-amplitude for that particular state. This leaves the sign of the reduced-width amplitude undetermined. More details on the R-Matrix formalism are given [here](http://www.jinaweb.org/events/matrix/05-R-matrix.pdf).